# Exception: Handshake Failed(Android-studio,online database)

Tags: php, android, mysql

So I'm trying to connect my app with a database and following a tutorial I got to a point that when I press the register button (meaning create a row in the database-mysql database on awardspace.com), I always get the error message:

> exception:hanshake failed.

I put on the browser: `www.mywebsite.com/Register.php` and it works fine.

Here is the `register-activity` code and the `register.php`.

**RegisterActivity:**

```
package com.example.geqwe1.ankle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText email;
    String spinner, Email,Spinner;
    Context ctx=this;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_register);
        spinner = "yolo";
    }

    public void register_register(View v) {
        Email = email.getText().toString();
        BackGround b = new  BackGround();
        b.execute(Email,spinner);
    }

    class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String email = params[0];
            String spinner = params[1];
            String data = "";
            int tmp;

            try{
                URL url = new URL("https://ankle.atwebpages.com/Register.php/");
                String urlParams = "email="+email+"&spinner"+spinner;

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                while((tmp=is.read())!= -1){
                    data+= (char)tmp;
                }
                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return data;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return  "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
            }
        }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                if (s.equals("")) {
                    s = "Data saved successfully.";
                }
                Toast.makeText(ctx, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}
```

**Register.php:**

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("fdb15.awardspace.net", "2432552_db", "mypassword", "2432552_db");

    $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users_table (user_id, email, gender) VALUES (NULL, '".$email."','".$gender."');";

?>
```

logcat after pressing register

```
08-29 14:19:25.968 1661-1706/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 3494:com.android.gallery3d/u0a47 (adj 906): empty #17
08-29 14:19:26.058 1661-2063/system_process D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 3494
08-29 14:19:26.100 1396-1428/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 716474 , only wrote 716400
08-29 14:19:26.176 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-29 14:19:26.541 4160-4167/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.465ms
08-29 14:19:26.939 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
08-29 14:19:26.941 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:429)
08-29 14:19:26.946 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
08-29 14:19:26.955 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
08-29 14:19:26.956 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
08-29 14:19:26.956 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
08-29 14:19:26.956 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
08-29 14:19:26.957 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
08-29 14:19:26.957 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
08-29 14:19:26.957 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
08-29 14:19:26.957 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
08-29 14:19:26.958 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
08-29 14:19:26.958 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
08-29 14:19:26.958 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
08-29 14:19:26.961 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.example.geqwe1.ankle.RegisterActivity$BackGround.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:55)
08-29 14:19:26.961 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.example.geqwe1.ankle.RegisterActivity$BackGround.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:40)
08-29 14:19:26.961 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
08-29 14:19:26.961 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-29 14:19:26.962 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
08-29 14:19:26.968 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
08-29 14:19:26.971 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
08-29 14:19:26.971 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
08-29 14:19:26.972 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
08-29 14:19:26.972 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:         ... 21 more
08-29 14:19:26.973 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:         Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
08-29 14:19:26.991 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:             ... 21 more
08-29 14:19:26.994 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:         Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xa7220b40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
08-29 14:19:26.997 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.c:192 0xa4179196:0x00000000)
08-29 14:19:26.998 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
08-29 14:19:26.998 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
08-29 14:19:26.998 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:             ... 20 more
08-29 14:19:27.000 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xa7220b40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
08-29 14:19:27.002 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.c:192 0xa4179196:0x00000000)
08-29 14:19:27.002 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
08-29 14:19:27.002 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
08-29 14:19:27.002 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:         ... 20 more
08-29 14:19:27.003 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xa7220b40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
08-29 14:19:27.003 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.c:192 0xa4179196:0x00000000)
08-29 14:19:27.003 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
08-29 14:19:27.003 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
08-29 14:19:27.004 4160-4332/com.example.geqwe1.ankle W/System.err:     ... 20 more
08-29 14:19:27.107 4160-4196/com.example.geqwe1.ankle D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5fd4e80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa5fcc970)
08-29 14:19:27.126 4160-4196/com.example.geqwe1.ankle E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
08-29 14:19:27.175 2630-4350/com.google.android.gms W/DriveInitializer: Background init thread started
08-29 14:19:27.189 4160-4196/com.example.geqwe1.ankle D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5fd4e80: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xa5fcc970)
08-29 14:19:27.689 2630-4350/com.google.android.gms W/DriveInitializer: Background init thread ended
08-29 14:19:29.327 1396-1429/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 1023969 , only wrote 871200
08-29 14:19:30.524 1661-1661/system_process W/WindowManager: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@91c59c0
08-29 14:19:45.011 1883-2706/com.android.phone I/OmtpVvmCarrierCfgHlpr: OmtpEvent:CONFIG_STATUS_SMS_TIME_OUT
08-29 14:19:45.011 1883-1883/com.android.phone I/RetryPolicy: discarding deferred status: configuration_state=4
08-29 14:19:45.013 1883-1883/com.android.phone D/VvmTaskScheduler: No more tasks, stopping service if no task are added in 5000 millis
08-29 14:19:45.014 1883-1883/com.android.phone D/VvmTaskScheduler: create task:com.android.phone.vvm.omtp.ActivationTask
08-29 14:19:45.014 1883-1883/com.android.phone D/RetryPolicy: retry #2 for com.android.phone.vvm.omtp.ActivationTask@a95c13 queued, executing in 5000
08-29 14:19:45.016 1883-1883/com.android.phone D/VvmTaskScheduler: minimal wait time:4998
08-29 14:19:45.018 1883-1883/com.android.phone D/VvmTaskScheduler: minimal wait time:4996
08-29 14:19:50.017 1883-2706/com.android.phone V/VvmTaskScheduler: executing task com.android.phone.vvm.omtp.ActivationTask@a95c13
08-29 14:19:50.037 1883-2706/com.android.phone I/VvmActivationTask: VVM content provider configured - vvm_type_cvvm
08-29 14:19:50.037 1883-2706/com.android.phone I/OmtpVvmCarrierCfgHlpr: OmtpEvent:CONFIG_ACTIVATING
08-29 14:19:50.057 1883-2706/com.android.phone V/OmtpMessageSender: Sending BINARY sms 'Activate:dt=15' to 122:1808
08-29 14:19:50.072 1883-1883/com.android.phone D/VvmStatusSmsFetcher: Request SMS successfully sent
08-29 14:20:00.025 1762-2002/com.android.systemui E/OpenGLRenderer: Corrupted GPU pixel buffer
08-29 14:20:05.652 3194-3309/com.google.android.talk I/Babel_ConcService: Acquired partial wake lock to keep ConcurrentService alive
08-29 14:20:05.653 3194-3309/com.google.android.talk I/Babel_ConcService: Released partial wake lock as ConcurrentService became idle
```

Comment: I think there is issue on certificate on your server side, may be they are not valid. Post complete logcat.

Comment: @VindhyaPratapSingh Ok I posted it. Is there for this issue to be solved by me?

Comment: As I am getting this is a protocol exception. I found this as result, "if we set default port as 80 when visit https server will produce this error".
It can occurs due to many reasons such as when your SSL certificate is not valid or self generated. Or not matching with your device certificate.
Or when an SSL connection is attempted on a non-SSL server. You can try with removing s use just http.

Comment: @VindhyaPratapSingh You sir just made my day!

Comment: Can you please share share what was the exact issue on your case.

Comment: @VindhyaPratapSingh I don't know what the exact issue was but I changed https to http and I didn't get exception handshake failed anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify my answer in comment, I am pointing out these case which can result **SSL Handshake Exception**

- If you are getting specifically **OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER** in 
  logcat. It occurs sometime when we set default port as 80 when visit https 
  server will produce this error.
- If you are getting specifically **TLSV1 or any other certificate name** in 
  logcat then it may be you SSL certificate on server is not valid or self 
  signed. Either you can change your protocols on server side or can check with 
  NOSSLFactory on Android Code.
- Or SSL connection attempted on a non-ssl server.

These are some generic cases there many other cases, you can edit this answer which will help others.